# Use phonegap build when creating our own plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

We have made a phonegap-project in eclipse, and created our own plugins with native code (and JS).
However, we want to also create the app in phonegap build.

Is it possible to use phonegap build when we use external plugins (created by us, and not supported by the https://build.phonegap.com/plugins)
If yes, does anybody have a good example or tutorial on this?

Comment: There is a big list of supported plugins here: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins
I bet you have to submit your plugin to their repository if you want to use it with Build.

Comment: the plugin is work-related, so I can not make it public.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. You'll need to build locally.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap Build does allow private/external plugins since December 2014.

http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/09/phonegap-build-new-features/

Comment: Switching to Cordova was a good decision, anyway. :) We did it twice and it helped in many ways.